# Calling gen_server:cast from Mod:handle_cast

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

This is the code I have:

```
handle_cast(start, #state{started = false} = State) ->
    gen_server:cast(self(), add_process),
    {noreply, State#state{started = true}};
handle_cast(add_process, State) -> ...
```

Is it ok to call `gen_server:cast` from insinde the `handle_cast` function? What I expect it to do is that `handle_cast` will return a new state and then the `add_process` message is processed immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct, except that the message might not be processed "immediately" - it is put on the message queue, and the messages before it in the queue will be processed first.

As you've probably figured out already, this applies to `gen_server:cast` and messages sent using `!`, but not to `gen_server:call`, which would cause a deadlock here.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by gen_server:call would cause a deadlock there? how?

Comment: If a gen_server process makes a call to itself, it would send a message and wait for a response — but the response would never arrive, because while it's waiting for the response it's not listening for calls.

Comment: So how do we make internal calls and still keep state consistent without races? since gen_server:cast is async and "may" return new state

Comment: Make a simple function call (usually to an internal function in the same module), not a gen_server call. gen_server calls are for when you need a different process to do something.

Comment: i have been having this design concern. Thanks